# Magento 2: Problem with Product Links

Tags: magento2, import, product-urls

During an Import to Update Product prices, I made a mistake. I leave the value for the Product Link empty. After the Import all Product URL change and got the value from the Product name. To face this mistake I delete the table catalog_product_entity_varchar and after that, I create a new table with a SQL Backup. Now in the Product Backend Page for each product, there is the right URL but in the frontend, it doesn't found. Only with the wrong URL. What can I do? I think it depends on the URL Rewrites!

Answer (score 0):

This [module](https://github.com/Iazel/magento2-regenurl) is been deprecated you can use this [module](https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls) instead

Download Using Composer;

```
composer require elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Regenerate url for all products and the global store

```
php bin/magento regenerate:product
```

Regenerate url for products with id (1, 2, 3, 4) for store 1

```
php bin/magento regenerate:product:url -s1 1 2 3 4
```